# how can I add a background image in the image view and the image I want it to show over the background image ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to put a patch in the background of the image view and then put the image on it. How can I do that. I am attaching an image for better understanding 
please help in doing this.
 [image]

Comment: @fahimParkar how do you edit it like this so that the image is visible?

Comment: just add ! before [] -- `![IMAGE][1]` Also you can have `![IMAGE][https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzKzA.jpg]`

Comment: did my answer solve your problem? if yes, accept the answer.

Comment: No it did not..

Comment: what are you looking for exactly? can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using SDWebImage for caching the images.

For displaying user profile, use it as UIButton and follow below code.

```
[userPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
     [[userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Photo"]] 
     forState:UIControlStateNormal 
     placeholderImage:[self adjustImageByLang:@"player_photo.png"]
];
```

`player_photo.png` is your patch image.

You are done